# How to set hadoop block size properly?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, size, block, hdfs

I've tried to combine my file to upload into HDFS into one file. So, the HDFS have files number smaller than before but with the same size. So, in this condition I get faster mapreduce time, because I think the process make fewer container (map task or reduce task).

So, I want to ask, how can I set the block size properly, to get faster mapreduce? Should I set bigger than default (minimze container number)?

Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

Do you know, why hadoop have strong and fast compute capacity? Because it divides a single big job into many small jobs. That's the spirit of hadoop.

And there are many mechanism to coordinate it work flow, maybe adjust the blocksize couldn't attain your target.

You can set the parameter "dfs.block.size" in bytes to adjust the blocksize.